# MySQL query performance between two options

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written two queries which return the same result, but I want use which is performance wise better

```
SELECT ID, INTERESTS 
FROM users 
WHERE CITY = (SELECT CITY FROM users WHERE ID = 124)

SELECT b.ID, b.INTERESTS 
FROM users a, users b 
WHERE a.CITY = b.CITY AND a.ID = 124
```

Comment: check the execution plan.. or time them.

Comment: Test it on production size data. If you can't tell, it doesn't matter. Also, you should learn to use ANSI joins - they've been in the SQL standard since 1992.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2577188/3973420

Answer (score 0):

First, you should stop using archaic syntax with commas in the `FROM` clause.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause; *always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Second, a performance question is best handled by checking performance on your data on your system.

Your second query is properly written as:

```
SELECT b.ID, b.INTERESTS
FROM users a JOIN
     users b 
     ON a.CITY = b.CITY AND a.ID = 124 ;
```

This should have fine performance.  Sometimes `EXISTS` can have slightly better performance:

```
select u2.*
from users u
where exists (select 1 from users u where u.city = u2.city and and u.id = 124);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### A couple of thoughts

1. For your two queries, look at the `EXPLAIN` plan to see how mysql is limiting the data

You can do this by running

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ID,INTERESTS FROM users WHERE CITY = (SELECT CITY FROM users WHERE ID=124)
EXPLAIN SELECT b.ID,b.INTERESTS FROM users a,users b WHERE a.CITY = b.CITY AND a.ID=124
```

I've found [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/) to be a hepful read when it comes to optimizing queries based on their explain plan.

2. For good performance, since you are basically joining on the `CITY` column, consider creating an index on the `CITY` column in the `users` table.

Indexes are a trade-off between space and performance.

You can create one by running

```
CREATE INDEX idx_city ON users(CITY);
```

Doing this should make both queries perform well.